# Octave does not recognise changes in .m files

Tags: matlab, oop, octave

I'm trying to run some simple octave scripts, but I face the following issue.

Suppose I have an error A in my script. When I try to run this script, octave reports me that it sees error A in, say, line 10, column 10. I comment out this line and try to run script again, but octave continues to report error A in line 10, column 10.

So, now the code.

my main scrips contains following:

```
clear; clc;

#test_image_path = "/home/roman/Documents/prog/Prototype/project/resources/image/1.jpg";
test_image_path = "/home/roman/Documents/prog/Prototype/project/resources/image/3x3.jpeg";

plotter_obj = plotter();

source_image = imread(test_image_path);
plotter_obj.add_plot(source_image);

xyz_image = custom_image_conversion_routines.rgb2ciergb(source_image);
plotter_obj.add_plot(xyz_image);

plotter_obj.draw()
```

When `plotter_obj.draw()` is called, following class should work:

```
classdef plotter < handle
  properties (Hidden, SetAccess = protected)
    column_no = 0;
    row_no = 0;
    plots = {}; 
  end

  methods
    function obj = plotter()
      disp('plotter created');
    end

    function add_plot(obj, plot)
      obj.plots{end + 1} = plot;
    end

    function draw(obj)
      vector_len = size(obj.plots)
      grid_axis_size = ceil(sqrt(vector_len));

      for index = 1:vector_len
        subplot(grid_axis_size, grid_axis_size);
        imshow(obj.plots{index});
      endfor
    end

  end

end
```

Octave reports the following error:

> error: 'len' undefined near line 18 column 20
>       error: called from
>           draw at line 18 column 18
>           rg_chromacity_based_wavelet_transform at line 15 column 1

But there's no `len` symbol mentioned in draw method anymore.

The only way I can get rid of the error message, is to shutdown octave and restart it.

What happens? Am I supposed to reset my working environment in some way after modifying my class method?

Comment: Post your code here!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you make a change to a class, you likely need to [clear that class](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/clear.html) for the changes to take effect.

```
clear -classes
```